# Promtail: error writing positions.yaml (too many open files)

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

I’m trying to collect almost 3GB of log files everyday with promtail.
Promtail runs fine until some hours and starts to throw the error such as:

Jul 07 14:54:53 ip-127.0.0.1 promtail-linux-arm64[74099]: level=error ts=2023-07-07T14:54:53.188346106Z caller=positions.go:179 msg="error writing positions file" error="open/local/promtail/.promtail_positions.yaml3507440037425283515: too many open files"

Jul 07 14:54:58 ip-127.0.0.1 promtail-linux-arm64[74099]: level=error ts=2023-07-07T14:54:58.078325647Z caller=positions.go:179 msg="error writing positions file" error="open /local/promtail/.promtail_positions.yaml6187472917671051760: too many open files"

Note:

Not running on containers and pods but on a VM
The config for loki and promtail are set accordingly to the size and they run on the same host (aarch64)

```
Earlier GitHub issues gave an impression to change the following
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 100000
fs.inotify.max_user_instances = 512
fs.inotify.max_queued_events = 100000

ulimit -n : 1000000
```

Ya, changed those and was not able to identify what was the problem.
Need Help…